# Highcharts Graph displaying 0 value continuously : Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I am trying to display the points on a graph using PHP Mysql, I saved the data into an array in php Variable and then passed that array into a Javascript array.

Now, What I want to do is that I want to show the array elements one by one after every one second. But what is Happening is that the graph plots `0` value countinuously on the Highchart.

Here is my Code :

```
numArray = [1,5,3,5,6,3,3,7,4,6,7,3,5,3,6,7,5,2,5,7,4,6,4,5,3,6,7,8,5,4,3,6,7,8,5,7,8,8,5,3,2,4,6,7,4,6,7] ;
/* Just for understanding */

var json_array =numArray ;

var i = 0;

function next() {  
 return json_array[i];
  i++;
}
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0],
                    chart = this;

                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y =next();
                        console.log(y) ;
                    series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
                }, 1000);

                setInterval(function() {
                    chart.redraw(false);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        animation: false,
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function() {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -1000; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push([
                    time + i * 10,
                    null
                ]);
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

Here is the Fiddle that  I have created :

https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/v7tdLr1j/2/

The Chart runs till infinite loop and show only `0` Value. I just want to show the array values till the End

Comment: nothing works after return change return statement to  return json_array[i++]

https://jsfiddle.net/q4g7duav/

Comment: awesome @Ashu. Just one thing. its not stopping after the arrray ends. is there any way to stop the graph when it reaches the end of the array?

Comment: you can stop the interval after the array has been completely plotted.

Answer (score 0):

First of there is no endpoint in your setInterval method. It will keep on calling after 1 sec. You cant even stop. First, have a separate function to form data. Let's say have series data initialized. Have as a global variable. then have the Promise to generate you x point.

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   var points [];
   setTimeout(function() {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
      y =next();
      points.push([x, y], false, true);
      if(your counter let says 1000 : points.lenght > 1000) {
        resolve(points) //resolve your points
      }
   }, 300);});
```

wrap above thins in function and return a promise and call that.

```
callYourDefinedFun().then(function(points) {
  // now you have points ready, series ready make your chart configuration and then 
 // call to render the chart
});
```

Comment: pardon my noobness, but I am really not familiar with promise resolve concept. the example that provided by @Ashu is working for me, its just that the graph is not stoping at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below demo with the result you probably want to achieve.

**Code:**

```
const numArray = [1, 5, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 5, 7, 4, 6, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5, 7, 8, 8, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 7];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        let chart = this,
          now = (new Date()).getTime(),
          i = 0;

        const interval = setInterval(function() {
          chart.series[0].addPoint([
            now + i * 1000,
            numArray[i]
          ]);

          i++;

          if (i === numArray.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [{}]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vf906wam/

Comment: this works very good for showing one plot each second. But when I am trying to plot multiple points in One second. the chart is fluctuating

for eg: on changing speed to 100 the charts start behaving weirdly, is their any way to accomplish that ?

Comment: Could you reproduce it? For more than one point you can use `series.setData()`.